# How to choose where children of a custom element will be located?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Hello I have a custom webcomponent and I want to decide where to put the children inserted by the upper (parent) element.

File of upper html element using my custom component:

```
  <custom-component>
    <custom-component2></custom-component2>
  </custom-component>
```

File describing custom-component inside structure:

```
<h5>title</h5>
 <p>paragraph</p>
```

Result in DOM:

```
  <custom-component>
        <custom-component2></custom-component2>
       <h5>title</h5>
       <p>paragraph</p>
 </custom-component>
```

What I want:

```
  <custom-component>
       <h5>title</h5>
       <p>paragraph</p>
        <custom-component2></custom-component2>
 </custom-component>
```

How can I choose where to put the content like ng-content in Angular or props.children in React? I am building a custom webcomponent library. Thank you

Comment: Can't you just use `<custom-component2>` inside of the content of `<custom-component>`?

Comment: there will not always be a custom-component2, it depends on the upper component. I can be a div or multiple divs...

Comment: You can try to attach `<custom-component2>` to the correct place in `<custom-component>` using the shadow dom (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM). Though this depends on how you 'get' `<custom-component2>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slots` for displaying parent oriented content. Furthermore, you can organise this by named slots.

This works in Angular with [Content Projection](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/).

You can give these `ng-content` names.

Comment: Yes I think so. You can test it out :)

Answer (score 1):

As @FloWy said, you can use `<slot>`.

With native Custom Elements, you'll need to use a Shadow DOM.

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-component', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    var sh = this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
    sh.innerHTML = `<h5>Title</h5>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        Slot content: <slot></slot>`
  }
} )
```

```html
<custom-component>
  <custom-component2>Child element</custom-component2>
</custom-component1>
```